# "movies in English" vs. "English movies"

Tags: american-english

In a English classroom, some classmates talks about the tips of learning English, Kenneth says

> To practice English, you could watch some English movies.

Should Kenneth say it this way?

> To practice English, you could watch some movies in English.

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/english)

> in or relating to the English language

> relating to or from England

Kenneth is trying to go with the first meaning. How should he say?

Comment: The way Kenneth says it would be perfectly understandable in context; if he wanted to be really precise he could have said _English-language movies_.

Comment: It would be *extremely* unusual to use the collocation ***English movies*** to mean ***movies made in England*** - they'd nearly always be called ***British movies***.